# select buttons orderly in userControl by press Tab key

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a UserControl with some buttons in it (`btnNew`, `btnCancel`, `btnEdit`).

I used this UserControl in another project. When I press the tab key in this project, the selection button doesn't change regular!

For example, I want that if the user presses the `Tab` key, first the `btnNew` button is selected, then the `btnEdit` button, and finally the `btnCancel` button.

But in this project, when pressing the `Tab` key, the `btnCancel` button is selected first.

I want to manage the tab order of the buttons myself, and not use the default. How can I do this?

Thanks...

Comment: TabOrder: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the order of how the buttons will be selected on tab press use the property

```
TabIndex
```

it defines the order the tabs will be selected. So set the tab index like the following

```
btnNew.TabIndex = 0;//selected first
btnCancel.TabIndex = 1;//the second
btnEdit.TabIndex = 2;//the last one
```

Answer (score 4):

When the form designer is open go to View > Tab Order this will allow you to set the tab order in a very simple and easy way.

Refer this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much knowledge on Windows Forms, As I know there will be a `TabIndex` property for each control.

You can set your order using that.

Answer (score 2):

Menu View-> [TabOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

or

manually set `TabIndex` for each control.

Answer (score 0):

> **To set the tab order of a control**
>
> 1. On the View menu, click Tab Order. This activates the tab-order selection mode on the form. A number (representing the TabIndex
>    property) appears in the upper-left corner of each control.
> 2. Click the controls sequentially to establish the tab order you want.
> 3. When you have finished, click Tab Order on the View menu again to leave tab order mode.

Quoted from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You could also change the `TabIndex` property of each of the controls individually in the Properties pane. Or change it programatically like so `btnNew.TabIndex = 0;`.